# Don't I have Bluetooth on Dell Latitude e6540?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, dell, wacom

I don't seem to have bluetooth on my laptop.

lsusb gives:

```
 Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:649d Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I want to start using a wacom wireless tablet and other wireless devices. What options do I have? Can I do it by buying a bluetooth adapter? I am not sure how it works. Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can always  buy a USB BT adapter.

Comment: It do have blutooth: Connectivity 10/100/1000 Gigabit Ethernet
Wireless LAN and WiMAX Options:
Intel® Centrino® Advanced-N 6235 + Bluetooth® 4.0
Intel® Centrino® Ultimate-N 6300
Dell Wireless 1506 (802.11g/n 1x1)
Mobile Broadband11 & GPS Options:
Dell Wireless™ 557011 HSPA+ (42Mbps) Mini Card - be sure to turn WiFi on with Bluetooth!  Most Wireless warns that WiFi and BT use same channel - hence the option to run them separate!